# Check if all elements of array equal to something

Tags: php

Have

```
$my_arr_1 = array ("denied","denied","denied");
$my_arr_2 = array ("denied","denied","allowed");
```

Need a func that would check if all elements in the array equal to something:

```
in_array_all("denied",$my_arr_1); // => true

in_array_all("denied",$my_arr_2); // => false
```

Is there a php native function like in_array_all?

If not, what would be the most elegant way to write such a func?

Comment: you want to check if all the elements have the same value?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Should probably be called **array_assert_elements( _array_ $array, _callable_ $callback )** instead of in_array_all as in_array works differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function in_array_all($value, $array)
{
  return (reset($array) == $value && count(array_unique($array)) == 1);
}
```

Comment: I like the elegancy of this solution

Answer (score 3):

```
function in_array_all($needle,$haystack){
  if(empty($needle) || empty($haystack)){
    return false;
  }

  foreach($haystack as $k=>$v){
    if($v != $needle){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

And if you wanted to get really crazy:

```
function in_array_all($needle,$haystack){
      if(empty($needle)){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$needle must be a non-empty string. ".gettype($needle)." given.");
      }
      if(empty($haystack) || !is_array($haystack)){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$haystack must be a non-empty array. ".gettype($haystack)." given.");
      }

      foreach($haystack as $k=>$v){
        if($v != $needle){
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of your code. But what about reversing the logic? Then you are able to use PHP's native function `in_array`.

```
$my_arr_1 = array ("denied","denied","denied");
$my_arr_2 = array ("denied","denied","allowed");

!in_array("allowed", $my_arr_1); // => true
!in_array("allowed", $my_arr_2); // => false
```

This entirely depends on your data set of course. But given the sample data, this would work. (Also, notice the negation `!` in front of each method call to produce the desired boolean result).

Comment: I believe he is looking for a more dynamic approach to searching arrays. Something that will allow him to search an array without needing to know the values that shouldn't be there, but just the values that should be there

Comment: I think you are right. The reason I posted this is that someone might stumble upon this thread because of an issue relating to the inverse problem (which the sample data may imply) :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
function in_array_all(array $haystack, $needle) {
    $count_map = array_count_values($haystack);
    // in your case: [ 'denied' => 2, 'allowed' => 1 ]
    return isset($count_map[$needle]) && $count_map[$needle] == count($haystack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Richard's solution is best but does not have one closing paren ;-) - here is fixed and abridged:

```
function in_array_all($needle,$haystack)
{
    if( empty($needle) || empty($haystack) ) return false;

    foreach($haystack as $v)
    {
        if($v != $needle) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```